# UIView borderWidth not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I want to have a rounded view with a black center and a colored border. When I set up my view like this:

```
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
myView.layer.borderWidth = 3
```

I get just a red round. But when I go to the Debug View Hierarchy, I see, that myView has a white border. Madness! What do I make wrong?

iPhone: [image: iPhone]
and Debug View Hierarchy: [image: Debug View Hierarchy]

Comment: Interesting, try to change this line`myView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor`  to `myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`

Comment: @k8mil, sorry, I have tried both. Just when I copied and pasted the code snippet, I used `layer.backgroundColor`. I edited my post

Comment: Have you tried putting an opacity of 0,5 on the red of your background color just to see if the white is showing through?

Comment: have you tried `maskToBounds` or `clipToBounds` value to `true`

Comment: @rjndra, yes, I tried both

Comment: @Ocunidee, I tried your suggestion. My rounded view becomes maroon, because of dark blue superview. But the border is visible only in the Debug View Hierarchy.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin give border with first & set float value like 3.0..

Comment: Have you tried `clipsToBounds` to `false`; ?

Comment: @Mannopson `false` is default value for `clipsToBounds`. So, yes.

Comment: @DSDharma 3 is a number for a snippet. I use a `CGFloat` constant.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin , yes problem is with your `CGFloat` constant

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S. What problem? I use this constant: `fileprivate let thickWidth: CGFloat = 9`

Comment: @ValentinShamardin , make sure by setting `break point` . When add it to `borderWidth`

Comment: @ValentinShamardin Can you add the code of setting cornerRadius of the view?

Comment: @Subramanianin `layoutSubviews` I use `self.myViews.forEach { $0.layer.cornerRadius = $0.frame.size.width/2 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom border and background like bellow

```
@IBDesignable class view_border_background: UIView {

private let gradientLayer : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

 //let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

// IBInspectable properties for the gradient colors
@IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = UIColor(hex: 0xe5e5e5)
@IBInspectable var middleColor: UIColor = UIColor(hex: 0xe5e5e5)
@IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = UIColor(hex: 0xe5e5e5)
@IBInspectable var bottomColorAlpha: CGFloat = 1.0
@IBInspectable var middleColorAlpha: CGFloat = 1.0
@IBInspectable var topColorAlpha: CGFloat = 1.0

// IBInspectable properties for rounded corners and border color / width
@IBInspectable var cornerSize: CGFloat = 0
@IBInspectable var borderSize: CGFloat = 1
@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = colorize(hex: 0x8bc218)
@IBInspectable var borderAlpha: CGFloat = 1.0

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {


    // set up border and cornerRadius
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerSize
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.withAlphaComponent(borderAlpha).cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderSize

    self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    // set up gradient

    gradientLayer.frame = rect
    let c1 = bottomColor.withAlphaComponent(bottomColorAlpha).cgColor
    let c2 = middleColor.withAlphaComponent(middleColorAlpha).cgColor
    let c3 = topColor.withAlphaComponent(topColorAlpha).cgColor
    gradientLayer.colors = [c3, c2, c1]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
   self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)


}
override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    gradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
    }

  }
```

Hex color convert

```
func colorize (hex: Int, alpha: Double = 1) -> UIColor {
let red = Double((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
let green = Double((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
let blue = Double((hex & 0xFF)) / 255.0
var color: UIColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha:CGFloat(alpha) )
return color
```

}

Just add "view_border_background" show identity inspector in VIView

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it, working fine in my simulator

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.size.width/2 //first make your view as rounded. 

    myView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor //convert into cgColor
    myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    myView.layer.borderWidth = 3
}
```

Comment: I tried both: UIView.backgroundColor and UIView.layer.backgroundColor. This doesn't help.